# Bash script to read user input in the middle of a sentence

Tags: bash, input, printf, echo

I am trying to build a script for educational purposes in bash and I am stuck.

I am looking to build a function that displays sentences from which a word is missing and the user should input it in it's middle, no separately.

Example: Ema and Dan are (to watch) TV.

The sentence should be completely displayed and between "are" and "(to watch)" the user should see the cursor, where he/she would input the missing word.

So far I haven't found nothing on Google.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me a tip. And if it doesn't work in bash what would be a reasonable alternative?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how what you've asked for is possible with standard `bash` utilities. The closest answer I can think of is the following which allows the user to use arrow keys to move edit the phrase as needed. After  is pressed, the response is available in `$REPLY`.

```
read -p $'Please replace the text within square brackets with the correct word or phrase:\x0a' -i "Ema and Dan are [to watch] TV." -e
```